# Pass data of specific <td> into php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with delete button in every row, that looks like this:

[image]

This is my code for each row of the table:

```
        </tr>
        {if $czyMaPakiety}
            {foreach item=pakiet from=$pakiety}
            <tr>
                <td class="dodaj">Pakiet:</td>
                <td>
                        <select name="pakiet[]">
                        {foreach item=item from=$klientTaryfaPakiety}
                                <option value="{$item.id_pakiet}" selected="{$item.nazwa}">{$item.nazwa_pakietu} kwota-> {$item.kwota} -> ilosc minut {$item.ilosc_minut}</option>
                        {foreachelse}
                                <option value="">Brak wolnych numerów</option>
                        {/foreach}
                        </select>
                </td>
                <td><a href="pakiety.php?id={$pakiet.id}" style="border: 1px solid #000000; background-color: #ADD1B3; margin-top: 10px;" name="pakiet_usun">Delete</a></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="pakiety_usu" style="border: 1px solid #000000; background-color: #ADD1B3; margin-top: 10px;" value="Usuń" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            {/foreach}
        {/if}
    <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="center"><input type="submit" name="abonament_edy" style="border: 1px solid #000000; background-color: #ADD1B3; margin-top: 10px;" value="Edytuj abonament" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="center"><input type="submit" name="abonament_usu" style="border: 1px solid #000000; background-color: #ADD1B3; margin-top: 10px;" value="Usuń abonament" /></td>
    </tr>
```

This is where i get data from each row in php:

```
if(isset($_POST['pakiety_usu'])) {
        print_r($_POST['pakiet'][0]);
}
```

Without this `[0]` in this line: `print_r($_POST['pakiet'][0]);` i get values of all printed rows. How can i access specific ID in my php code, when i click specific `DELETE` button. I would like to press for example second delete button and access data of the second `Pakiet` row.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the index of each packet in the packet array, 
in line 7, it should be like

```
<select name="pakiet[$index]">
```

then you can access each packet in php by it index

```
if(isset($_POST['pakiety_usu'])) {
        print_r($_POST['pakiet'][$index]);
}
```